# Blurring a section of an image with bootstrap scalability

Tags: css, image, blur

I am trying to blur a portion of the image behind the text but not the text and not anything outside of the box (code below). I would also appreciate a quick explanation too, if possible, as I am trying to understand it as well. I have messed around and got close-ish.

HTML:

```
 <div class="banner">
     <div class="container-fluid text-center">
       <h1>Tex Text Text</h1>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner { 
   height:200px;
   background-size:cover; 
   background-position:center center; 
   background-repeat:no-repeat; 
   background-image:url('sun.jpg');
}


.banner h1 {
   color:white;
   border: 3px solid white;
   padding: 20px;
   margin: 50px;
}
```

Here is an image of my current banner of which I want to blue the sunflower but over the text up to the white border.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hZnH.png)

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to have a text in front of an img and blur the img?

Comment: Yes but only a portion of the image, the bit that is behind the text and the text border

Comment: Edited to add image link for clarity

Comment: Um can you show what you want to achieve? I cant seem to get what you really want

Comment: @Kode.Error404  if you have a look at [link](http://imgur.com/fK9ggSJ) that is what I currently have, I have greyscaled the bit that I want to blur and as you can see the grey also resizes correctly with the view port.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like this Fiddle here?
(Found on the net)
http://jsfiddle.net/KodeError404/sE4Fv/723/

Even though it does not use bootstrap but you could adapt and put your text and adjust the CSS to fit your text in the `<div>`

Do remember to change the width/height to see your desired height of the height/width!(Now its in % meaning in ratio)